# Build Next.JS and tailwindcss

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I use TailwindCSS and NextJs for my app.
Everything is working when I `npm run dev` but when I `npm run build` then `npm run start` I have some classes that aren't working. For exemple in this code, `h-20 / text-white` don't work but other tailwind classes are perfectly working...

```
<div class="flex text-white font-semibold cursor-pointer">
<div class="flex-1 h-20 center-hv text-center bg-blue-primary hover:bg-blue-hover button-shadow">
    <div>
        <div>Acheter 200 €</div>
    </div>
</div> 
</div>
```

There is my confs :

```
//next.config.js

module.exports = {
    images: {
      domains: ["picsum.photos"],
    },
    env: {
      customKey: 'my-value',
    }
  }
```

```
//postcss.config.js

module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

```
//tailwind.css

module.exports = {
  purge: ['./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}', './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundColor: theme => ({
        ...theme('colors'),
        'blue-primary': '#A9C4D2',
        'blue-secondary': '#bbd9e8',
        'blue-hover': '#74afcd',
        'alert-info': '#d5e9f3',
        'alert-warning': '#ffd585',
        'alert-danger': '#ffb3b3'
      }),
      textColor: theme => ({
        ...theme('colors'),
        'blue-primary': '#A9C4D2',
        'blue-secondary': '#bbd9e8',
        'blue-hover': '#74afcd',
        'alert-info': '#d5e9f3',
        'alert-warning': '#ffd585',
        'alert-danger': '#ffb3b3'
      }),
    },
    flex: {
      '1': '1 1 0%',
      '2': '2 2 0%',
      '3': '3 3 0%',
      '4': '4 4 0%',
      '5': '5 5 0%',
      auto: '1 1 auto',
      initial: '0 1 auto',
      inherit: 'inherit',
      none: 'none',
    }
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

```
//jsconfig.json

{
    "typeAcquisition": {
        "include": ["jest"]
    }
}
```

```
//_app.js

import Navigation from '../componsants/navigation/Navigation'
import '../styles/globals.css'
import 'tailwindcss/tailwind.css'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {

  return (
    <>
      <div className="mtb">
        <Navigation />
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

I don't know if you have any ideas ?
I followed tailwind docs, but it looks like it's not enough ahah

Thx

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in an other post and testing
Because I have some components that are on conditionnal rendering and while building my app tailwind don't create the classes

To solve this you can :

- Delete the purge in tailwind conf (but it should be temporary)
- Create components and declaring all the classes you have to

Answer (score 0):

If some classes are not working, and another working = check your `tailwind.css`

Also, you have the example [Nextjs - Tailwind](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-tailwindcss)

P.S. [Your code test](https://play.tailwindcss.com/qABOstkMMi)